# QListWidget add item at the bottom of the list

Tags: c++, qt, qlistwidget

I'm making a messaging app using Qt5. I use a QListWidget to display the messages, and I want the message that the user sends to be added at the *bottom* of the list. I have tried this:

```
QString message_content = "new message";
messages_list.insertItem(0, message_content);
```

but the message still appeared at the *top* of the QListWidget. Using QListWidget::insertItem with index -1 did not work either, resulting in the messages appearing at the top like the screenshot below:
[image]

The outcome that I want is to have the new message appear below the "this is an old item" item. How can I achieve this effect?

Comment: also you can instantiate a QGridLayout and set it to your QListWidget and then in the layout you can put your message every where you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the `addItem()` method:

```
messages_list.addItem(message_content);
```